# Getting profile picture of friends from facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

Thats all I have tried.

```
void APICallback(FBResult result)                                                                                              
    {                                                                                                                              
        Debug.Log("APICallback");                                                                                                
        if (result.Error != null)                                                                                                  
        {                                                                                                                          
            Debug.LogError(result.Error);                                                                                                                                                                                         
            FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,picture)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, APICallback);     
            return;                                                                                                                
        }                                                                                              
        profile = Util.DeserializeJSONProfile(result.Text);                                                                        
        Name = profile["first_name"];
        friends = Util.DeserializeJSONFriends(result.Text);
        Debug.Log (Name);
        foreach (object friend in friends) {
            Dictionary<string, object> friendData = friend as Dictionary<string, object>;
            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> keyval in friendData)
            {
                Debug.Log(keyval.Key + " : " + keyval.Value.ToString());
            }
            Dictionary<string, object> pictureData = Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(friendData["picture"].ToString()) as Dictionary<string, object>;
            Dictionary<string, object> pic = pictureData["data"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
            Debug.Log(pic["url"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

It Gives me the friends name and id, but i need picture as well, the above query works fine on fb api graph explorer and gives the url of picture, but on unity it is not working. Please help if somebody can. Thanks

Comment: Can you include the exact result you get in the question?

Comment: Debug.Log(keyval.Key + " : " + keyval.Value.ToString());
this gave me id: 786453, name: Rehman
I need picture too.

Comment: But that's only the method where you treating the result. Where do you send request in the first place? May be you only modified the request here, where you repeat it, and forgot to include picture parameter whenever you send the first request?

Answer (score 1):

That's the way I get picture from a facebook userID in a coroutine :

```
WWW url = new WWW("https" + "://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?width=64&height=64"); 

Texture2D textFb = new Texture2D(64, 64, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);

yield return url;
url.LoadImageIntoTexture(textFb);
```

Then use your Texture2D where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary pic = pictureData["data"] as Dictionary;

this line must be like this;

Dictionary pic = Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(friendData["data"].ToString()) as Dictionary;